# Android 5.0 incoming call does not invoke Activity.onPause() call any more?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, incoming-call

I have an app that has code to handle incoming call as part of its function. It depends on the fact that incoming calls will invoke Activity.onPause(). However, on Samsung S6 with Android v5.0.2, incoming call event does not seem to call that method anymore.

Have I missed anything? If not, is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested Android 5.1, and the incoming call does not invoke onPause. But it the call is answered, then onPause is being invoked.

What I don't understand is why onStop is not being called, if the activity is not visible when the call is answered.